# Результаты алгоритма K- средних

Tags: алгоритм, кластеризация

Результаты алгоритма K- средних могут значительно отличатся в зависимости от случайного выбора центров кластеров. Это понятно логически. Алгоритм может застрять в локальном минимуме.Как это понять? как технически аргументировать это ?

Comment: А что именно непонятно? Если вы знаете, что такое локальный максимум, по идее вы можете легко построить какой-нибудь наглядный пример и аргументировать этим.

Comment: А вот и пример, кстати. Смотрите рисунок: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.8B_k-means